# Separability of a $\sigma$-algebra generated by an algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X:(Ω,\mathcal{F})$ be a measurable set and $\mathcal{F}=\sigma(C)$ where $C$ is an algebra .

Now We define $B_\mathcal{w}=\underset{\mathcal{w}∈A,A∈C}{\cap}A$, which suggests the intersection of all sets in $C$ that contain $\mathcal{w}$.

Similarly, we define $\mathcal{F}_\mathcal{w}=\underset{\mathcal{w}∈A,A∈\mathcal{F}}{\cap}A$,which suggests the intersection of all sets in $\mathcal{F}$ that contain $\mathcal{w}$.

If there exists another element $x$ which does not equal to $\mathcal{w} $ and $x$ belongs to $B_\mathcal{w}$. Now I think its trivial that $x$ belongs to $\mathcal{F}_\mathcal{w}$ but I couldn't give a precise proof.

Moreover, could we replace the condition "$C$ is an algebra" by "$C$ is an arbitrary set class which generates $\mathcal{F}$" and get the same conclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $\mathscr{E}\subset \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ *separates points* if for every $x,y\in \Omega$, if $x\neq y$ then there is some $E\in\mathscr{E} $ such that exactly one of $x$ or $y$ belongs to $E$.

> $\mathscr{E}$ separates points iff $\sigma(\mathscr{E})$ separates points.

$\Rightarrow)$ Trivial.

$\Leftarrow)$ Fix $x,y\in\Omega$ with $x\neq y$. Suppose $\mathscr{E}$ does not separate $x$ and $y$. Let
$$
\mathfrak{X}:=\{A\subset \Omega: \{x,y\}\subset A\vee \{x,y\}\cap A=\emptyset\}
$$
You can check that $\mathfrak{X}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. By our assumption, $\mathscr{E}\subset\mathfrak{X}$, so $\sigma(\mathscr{E})\subset \mathfrak{X}$, so $\sigma(\mathscr{E})$ does not separate $x$ and $y$.

Remark: $\mathscr{E}$ was an arbitrary collection of subsets of $\Omega$, not necessarily an algebra.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!